# Using Scenekit, how can I get an identity quaternion?

Tags: alignment, constraints, linear-algebra, scenekit, quaternions

Ah, go on then.

I'd like to create a [`SCNTransformConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntransformconstraint) orientation constraint so that a [`SCNNode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode) is always oriented to the world's x, y & z axes, no matter how the node's parents are oriented / move about.

I can create an orientation constraint working in world space like this:

```
let orientationConstraint = 
SCNTransformConstraint.orientationConstraint(inWorldSpace: true) {
  (node, orientation) -> SCNQuaternion in
  return <<<need quaternion identity here>>>
}

node.constraints = [orientationConstraint]
```

But I need by constraint callback to provide the [multiplicative identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultiplicativeIdentity.html) quaternion. When using [quaternions to describe orientation and rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) as scene kit does, the quaternion identity represents no rotation. Or an orientation in world coordinates that is aligned to the world.

This is analogous to the way that scaling by 1 gives the same scale. And setting a scale to 1 resets something to have no scaling.

For scene kit matrices there is `SCNMatrix4Identity`. Or, the additive identity for scene kit vectors: `SCNVector3Zero`.

How can I get the quaternion identity for multiplication?

Comment: What did you try so far? SO is a place for more specific questions (i.e. your code is not working)

Comment: Can I burn all my reputation with one question? That'd be something.

Comment: meh, you'll be fine and I like the humor, it is Friday after all but for quality sake let me also link to an [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173271/questions-in-titles-need-to-be-repeated-why)  that explains what the title should convey and what should be in the body. Take care.

Comment: :-) Thanks @rene, have a fantastic weekend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does not appear to be a `SCNQuaternionIdentity`.

The identity quaternion can be constructed with `SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 1)`.

Be careful not to use the default constructor `SCNQuaternion()`. It is equivalent to `SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)`, which doesn't represent a valid orientation.